# Multiple Beacon Consumer and beacon is not detecting using AltBeacon

Tags: java, android, kotlin, altbeacon

I am using altbeacon library in one of my android projects. In that project BeaconConsumer is already implemented in one of the activities. When I try to implement beacon detection in my part of the code beacon is not detecting.

But when i remove the BeaconConsumer code from the previously written code, then my code works and detects beacon.

This is the log when the beacon is not detecting. Why are there multiple consumers and is it the problem? If so, how can I remove multiple consumers.

```
 I/System.out: ---------onBeaconServiceConnect
 D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
 D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15
 D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19
 D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v
 D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
 D/BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor: Register calls: global=6 instance=6
 D/BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor: Register calls: global=7 instance=7
 D/BeaconManager: consumer count is now: 2
 D/BeaconManager: This consumer is not bound.  Binding now: MainActivity@11b9235
 D/BeaconManager: Not starting beacon scanning service. Using scheduled jobs
 D/BeaconLocalBroadcastProcessor: Register calls: global=8 instance=8
 D/BeaconManager: consumer count is now: 3
 D/BeaconManager: Unbinding
 D/BeaconManager: Not unbinding from scanning service as we are using scan jobs.
 D/BeaconManager: Before unbind, consumer count is 3
 D/BeaconManager: After unbind, consumer count is 2
```

This is the class i am using

```
class BeaconsDataSource(private val context: Context) : BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier,MonitorNotifier {

    private val beaconManager: BeaconManager =
            BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context)

    private val region = Region("myRegion", null, null, null)

    private lateinit var data: Step
    private var listener: ((Step) -> Unit)? = null
    override fun getApplicationContext(): Context = context

    override fun unbindService(p0: ServiceConnection?) {
        applicationContext.unbindService(p0!!)
    }

    override fun bindService(p0: Intent?, p1: ServiceConnection?, p2: Int): Boolean {
        
        return applicationContext.bindService(p0, p1!!, p2)
    }

    override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        BeaconManager.setDebug(true)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
                .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
                .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
                .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"))
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
                .add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))


        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers()
        beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()

        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this)
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this)

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region)
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(p0: MutableCollection<Beacon>, p1: Region?) {
      
            data = Step.ENTER_NUMBER
            notifyListeners()

    }

    private fun notifyListeners() {
        listener?.invoke(data)
    }


    fun requestBeaconsUpdate(listener: (Step) -> Unit) {
        this.listener = listener
        beaconManager.bind(this)
    }

    fun stopBeaconsUpdate() {       
        beaconManager.unbind(this)
    }

    override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(p0: Int, p1: Region?) {
        val msg = "---------did determine state for region $p0"
        Log.d("TAG", msg)
    }


    override fun didEnterRegion(p0: Region?) {
        val msg = "-----------did enter region"
        val zone = p0.toString()
        Log.d("TAG", "----------Enter in region")
        val text = "Enter in $zone"
        Log.d("TAG", msg)
    }

    override fun didExitRegion(p0: Region?) {
        val msg = "------------did exit region"
        Log.d("TAG", msg)
    }

}
```

This is my livedata class which i am calling from viewmodel

```
class BeaconsLiveData() : LiveData<Step>() {

    private val beaconDataSource = BeaconsDataSource(App.getAppContext())

    private val listener = { data: Step ->
        value = data
      
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        beaconDataSource.requestBeaconsUpdate(listener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        beaconDataSource.stopBeaconsUpdate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @davidgyoung i added the code

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what is causing the multiple bind operations but that likely is contributing to your detection problems.  I suspect it has something to do with the LiveData lifecycle.  Debugging this is unfortunately more involved than possible (for me) looking at the code snippet.

In general you should design your system so it calls `beaconManager.bind(...)` and `.unbind(...)` infrequently.  Doing so frequently causes problems as it will start and stop services which is a heavy weight mechanism.

I did create a working Kotlin sample app [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin) in case that is helpful to you.  This sample demonstrates using `MutableLiveData` to share beacon detection data from a central class that is doing the detection to your Activity.  The central class in this case is an Android application class, but it could just as well be any singleton with a long lifecycle.  The key thing is that it calls `bind(...)` once when it starts up, and won't call it again until you are done working with beacons.